# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement. The following APKs or app bundles are available to 64-bit devices,

Tags: java, helper, sketchware

The following APKs or app bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [12]

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

[[This the app build config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTdeG.jpg)]

[This are my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B50up.jpg)

What can i do for sove this error.this is
My code in building config java

```
/** Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY */
package com.bdd.musckyvpn;

public final class BuildConfig {
    
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true"); 
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "de.blinkt.openvpn"; 
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug"; 
    public static final String FLAVOR = ""; 
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = -1; 
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "";
```

There is solution in google but not sure
[How i can use this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqTO9.jpg)